# How to access a column in a row using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This may be a noob question. I have a table called `user_thoughts`. I am making a `Delete` button, which on click, will delete the "thought". I have two rows in my table:

**Row 1:**

```
 id - 106
 message - This is message 1
 added_by - AliceP
```

**Row 2:**

```
 id - 107
 message - This is message 2
 added_by - AliceP
```

Here is what I have so far (del_post.php):

```
<?php include("connect.php"); ?>

<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["user_login"])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $username = $_SESSION["user_login"];
}

/**************************/

// get id of all posts by logged in user
$get_id = "SELECT id FROM user_thoughts WHERE added_by ='$username'";
$run_query = mysqli_query($connect, $get_id);
    while ($row_query = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query)) {
        $tho_id = $row_query['id'];
        $comment_assigned_to_id = ['message'];

     $delete_query = mysqli_query ($connect, "DELETE FROM user_thoughts WHERE id = '$tho_id' '");
     header ("Location: /profile_page/$username");

    }
?>
```

If I want to delete the thought `This is message 1`, I click delete, and it will delete all the messages by `AliceP`. How can I get the id of the current message, and then delete just that message?

Comment: You have the query inside the while loop meaning it is going to delete them all, you need to do this by using ajax or use a link that you click and use GET to create the delete function

Comment: I have gotten rid of the while loop completely, so it now reads `$row_query = mysqli_fetch_array($run_query);`. This seems to work better in the sense that it is now deleting one post at a time, but it seems to be deleting the oldest `thoughts` when I click delete. No matter which post I hover over and click delete, the oldest thought will always get deleted.

Comment: How are you sending the data to this file? Are you sending it through post/get or not at all

Comment: At the moment, I have implemented neither. But I am now thinking I need a `$_GET` variable to get the id?

Comment: From my understanding, I thought the `$_GET` superglobal can only be used to obtain data from forms written in HTML? Nevertheless, I have tried `$getid = $_GET['id'];` and edited the delete query to ` $delete_query = mysqli_query ($connect, "DELETE FROM user_thoughts WHERE id = '$getid'");`, but the page simply refreshes, with nothing being deleted.

Comment: You would while through all off your posts and add a <a href="del_post.php?id='.$row_query['id'].'">Delete this </a> this will allow you to use the get super global

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104801/discussion-between-freddy-and-adam-hull).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

At the bottom of your script, create a form, and within the form (using results of the SELECT statement in a loop):

- display the row
- create a button with the name="delete" and the value=id (id of the row)

Step 2:

At the top of your script, add the code that will (when the form is submitted) extract the value of $_GET["delete"] or $_POST["delete"] (depending on whether you are using GET or POST form method).

If there is no value, skip the deleting portion.

Create & execute the delete statement based on the extracted value of the row id.